# Previous Throws Knowledge in Problem of Dice

Tags: probability

I started reading "Ten Great Ideas About Chance" by Persi Diaconis & Brian Skyrms. In the book, the *problem of dice* is described:

> A player has undertaken to throw a 6 in 8 throws of a die. The stakes have been settled, and the 3 throws have been taken without obtaining a 6. What proportion of the stake would be fair to give the player to forego his fourth throw (just the fourth).

The solution that is given assumes that the probability of winning in the fourth throw is 1/6, however, if we already know that the first 3 throws did not yield a 6, wouldn't it be a 1/3 chance of rolling a 6 in the fourth throw since 3 of the first 6 rolls already failed to give a 6, and we expect to see a 6 at some point in the first 6 throws?

I feel like the solution given disregards the information about the first 3 throws, much like in the Monty Hall problem where you can't say that there is a 1/2 chance of winning the car after the first door is open, because that disregards the information you had previously (making the real probability of winning 2/3).

Comment: That's the entire point. The first three rolls of a fair die tell you nothing at all about what the next roll would be. The Monty Hall problem is entirely different because the probability changes with the knowledge.

Comment: I see. I was thinking that the first three rolls had to tell you something about the next rolls, or else the dice wouldn't truly be a fair dice. I thought probability was a statistical reflection of reality, but I guess it's simply a quantitative model. I'm sure I'll learn more as I progress through the book! There seem to be more concepts/interpretations at play than I'm currently aware of.

Comment: It's the reverse: *because* the fairness of the die is not in question, the first three tries will tell you nothing about the next five.

Comment: I've been reading some more stuff online, and I think my issue was that there's different types of probabilities. I was thinking about it from a more science/statistics standpoint: what they call experimental probability. The book is talking about theoretical probability. I think in real life you need to know which one you are dealing with in order to know if the previous tries tell you something or not. For other examples in which the probability given to you is calculated experimentally/statistically, the above way of thinking would do you no good, I believe.

Comment: So even with a fair coin, if we are talking about experimental probability, as they do in science, the coin should give you a 6 in the first 6 rolls, and if it doesn't, then your chances increase considerably on the 7th and 8th rolls.

Comment: No, that's not how experimental probability works, either. You cannot expect a greater chance of a particular result of an independent sequence of random results, after carrying out part of that sequence, because that's what *independent* and *random* together mean: you can't use prior results to predict the next!